# oracle sql date format -1 month

Tags: sql, oracle, date, format

I want the DEP_DATE to match the PERIOD_TO for 1 month previou, using mm-yy match (the days are different)

Example **DEP_DATE = JUL-16** to match with **Period_to = JUN-16**

in my Where clause...
**and to_char(itny.DEP_DATE, 'mm-yy') = to_char(xch.PERIOD_TO,'mm-yy')-1**

I can match exact month-year but it doesn't like the -1 at the end of period_to to get the month previous.

I've tried various to_date but no joy.

thanks all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hi,
You can use below logic,

```
(trunc(itny.DEP_DATEe,'mm'),-1)
```

mm -1 derives you previous month. Apply this syntax to your requirement. Need to convert your format to date, just take the day values as some default

Answer (score 2):

One method is to subtract the month before formatting as a string:

```
to_char(itny.DEP_DATE, 'mm-yy') = to_char(add_months(xch.PERIOD_TO, -1), 'mm-yy')
```

Another method is to just use date comparison:

```
itny.DEP_DATE >= add_months(trunc(xch.PERIOD_TO, 'MM'), -1) and
itny.DEP_DATE < trunc(xch.PERIOD_TO, 'MM')
```

Comment: thank you both, I used this ... to_char(add_months(xch.PERIOD_TO, +1), 'mm-yy') and it worked perfectly.